# Temperature Calculator for Java

Tags: java, class, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am receiving errors during compilation. It's expecting a `.class`. I don't think it should require one. I'm pretty new at coding so forgive my ignorance. I also would like some guidance on how to nullify Case when the user inputs C or F so they can put c or f and not get an error messages.

This is my code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.InputMismatchException;
  public class TempCALC
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
  System.out.println("This Program will allow the user to calculate temperature.");
  calculateTemp();
}
private static void calculateTemp() {
  int F;
  int C;
  F=0;
  C=1;
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a F to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius.");
  System.out.println("Please enter a C to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.");
  int option = input.nextInt();
  if (int=0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit.");
    ftoc();
  } else if (int= 1) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in degrees Celsius.");
    ctof();
  } else {
    System.out.println("ERROR PLEASE ENTER A F OR A C TO PROCEED!");
  }
}
private static void ftoc() {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Double celsius = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(celsius + "celsius is" + ((celsius * 9 / 5.0) + 32) + "Fahrenheite");
  calculatetemp();
}
private static void ctof() {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Double Fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(Fahrenheit + "Fahrenheit is" + ((Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9.0)) + "Celsius");
  calculatetemp();
}
private static void print(String string); {
  System.out.println("\n" + string);
}
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at toLowerCase(), I will put an example in a sec: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_tolowercase.htm

Comment: on line 23 and 26 i'm getting a .class expected. "if (int=0).class" makes no sense to me so i have to be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (int=0)
```

This is not valid Java syntax. [`int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is a type not a variable. You meant to write:

```
if(option == 0)
```

Notice the `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment). 
This is the flow you meant to implement:

```
if (option == 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit.");
    ftoc();
  } else if (option == 1) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in degrees Celsius.");
    ctof();
  } else {
    System.out.println("ERROR PLEASE ENTER A F OR A C TO PROCEED!");
  }
```

If you wish for the user to enter `f` or `c` instead to mention the degrees, you will need to use:

```
String option = input.next();
```

To get a `String` instead of an `Integer`.

And then:

```
if (option.equals('F') { ... }
else if(option.equals('C') { ... }
else { ... }
```

If you want your input to be case-insensitive take a look at [`toLowerCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa989676(v=vs.80).aspx)  or [`toUpperCase`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_touppercase.htm) and apply it to your needs (there is an answer here that shows its use).

Comment: ok thank you but now i'm receiving an  "incomparable types: java.util.Scanner and int" error message. so do i need to change the variables i defined in the first few lines and if so how would you recommend doing so?

Comment: in lines 22 and 25 AKA the if "(input == 0) {" and "if (input == 1) {"

Comment: Notice in my code it's **`option == 0`** and not `input == 0`. Change your code to that and it will work :)

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you so much you have been very helpful! I think i can get the rest working on my own but ill be sure to let you know if i have any troubles! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`int` is reserved key word in java you can not used it with expression to compare,you should use his value like this:

```
    int option = input.nextInt();
      if (option ==0) {
```

Not `if (int=0) {` and `=` is used to assign but `==` is used to check equality.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to check the validation in your ifs statements, as the previous answers mentioned.

Also, I think that your actual conversion formulas are swapped.

Then, in order to receive **either 'C' or 'c'**:

Read a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), instead of an [int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

```
String option = input.next();
```

And then **convert** all the input to **lowercase**:

```
if (option.toLowerCase().equals("f"))
```

---

Here is the complete example:

```
public class TempCALC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This Program will allow the user to calculate temperature.");
        calculateTemp();
    }

    private static void calculateTemp() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a F to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a C to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.");
        String option = input.next();
        if (option.toLowerCase().equals("f")){
            System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit.");
            ftoc();
        }else if (option.toLowerCase().equals("c")){
            System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in degrees Celsius.");
            ctof();
        }else{
            System.out.println("ERROR PLEASE ENTER A F OR A C TO PROCEED!");
        }
    }

    private static void ftoc() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double celsius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(celsius + "celsius is" + ((celsius * 9 / 5.0) + 32) + "Fahrenheite");
        calculatetemp();
    }

    private static void ctof() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double Fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Fahrenheit + "Fahrenheit is" + ((Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9.0)) + "Celsius");
        calculatetemp();
    }

    private static void print(String string){
        System.out.println("\n" + string);
    }

    private static void calculatetemp(){
        System.out.println("\nInside calculateTemp");
    }
}
```